# Configuring LM35 to read below 0 degrees C

Tags: resistors, temperature, pulldown, lm35

I read online that the LM35 has a temperature range of -55°C to 150°C, but when testing I found that it was unable to go below 0°C.

This is the code I've written to read from the temperature sensor. I am reading it using an ADC pin on the RP2040:

```c
float read_temp(int ADCPin) {

    // Select ADC input 3
    adc_select_input(ADCPin);

    uint16_t result = adc_read();
    float converted_value = result * 0.00122246 - 0.0254607;
    
    // Conversion for LM35
    float temperature_conversion = 100*converted_value;


    return temperature_conversion;

}
```

In the datasheet I found that I my need to construct this circuit

[image]

I don't understand how to get a negative supply voltage on this pulldown resistor. I only have the RP2040 and a 5V regulator. I don't know how I would construct a circuit to achieve this negative supply voltage.

Let me know how I would achieve this.

Edit: All the information I've gotten about the LM35 has come from [this datasheet.](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf)

Comment: *I read online that the LM35 has a temperature range of -55°C to 150°C, but when testing I found that it was unable to go below 0°C.* You could have the LM35D variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a negative voltage with a cheap module. But, that will just lead to another problem, the RPi can't handle negative voltages.

The datasheet has a recommended circuit. You will need to read two voltages and subtract them, shouldn't be an issue with an RPi.

[image]

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf

Comment: Ah.. you type faster than me. Note that with a 5V supply and 2 diode drop it will be close to the 4V supply minimum.

Comment: Note that the "current drain" is 60 uA. 2 diodes drop should be lower than 1 V.

Comment: @Antonio51 Depends on the temperature. If mounted near the sensor and it's at -55C their \$V_F\$ would be higher, an LTspice sim shows 1.3 V for two 1N4148's at that temp.

Comment: Confirmed https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtOP7.png